# ASP.net relative path is broken after publish

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 web application that is working normally on the localhost. When publishing it the paths are not loaded correctly.
I have published it to : www.example.com/myAPP and in the code I am using the tilde (~) for the paths , for example:

```
~/content/style.css
```

so instead of the path to be mapped to `www.example.com/myAPP/content/style.css`
It is mapped to `www.example.com/content/style.css`

So an error of not found is thrown.

I tried to add this to the global,asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Context.Items["IIS_WasUrlRewritten"] = false;
}
```

but not solved

Comment: Are you encountering same problem while using `@Url.Content("~/content/style.css")` helper? Sounds like you're experiencing URL rewrite issue, this article may be related to your issue: [URL rewrite issues with ASP.NET Razor](https://madskristensen.net/blog/url-rewrite-may-break-aspnet-razor-3).

Comment: checked and applied the solution, but the error not solved

Comment: @PlexisPlexis Try referencing the style using `@Styles.Render("~/content/style.css")`